# Cordova-camera plugin

Tags: ionic-framework

When adding cordova camera plugin into my project then i am facing cordova build problem as follows:

Step 1: Adding ionic cordova camera plugins

Step 2: try to build the native app using `ionic cordova build android --debug`

then the following error is displaying

> Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
>   D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list:
>     Error while merging dex archives:
>     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android --debug exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Check your Java Version. i think your Java is outdated. please update java And also check android SDK

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be from your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and find `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, you will find two line for this. Comment one of them and keep only one `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Then try to run again.

This will may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I change cordova-camera plugin version from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0 and now it works well this may be ionic v4 plugin issue

Answer (score 0):

install the latest cordova platform[

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ue74.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).